# sending an image from java server to android

Tags: java, android, tcp, javax.imageio

i'm trying to send an image from a java server to an android device.

i can send the image from java server to java client using the ImageIO but since android doesn't support ImageIO i dont know how to receive the image from the java server.

I tried to convert the image to byte array then decode it on the android but it is not working probably and the byte array comes with a lot of problems size and length wise.

if anyone can point a correct way of sending an image and read it on an android device i would be very thankful.

edit ...

figured it out it is actually was simpler then i expected

client side 
load the image in a bufferedimage
use ImageIO to write the image to the server stream

server side
decode the stream into bitmap using bitmapFactory

Comment: Use BitmapFactory, in lieu of ImageIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion creating an API using PHP then with the API you can download the image in the byte form and after getting the byte array you can convert the byte to bitmap using this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```